# Opening an input dialog in Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to open at a certain point an input dialog, whose input I would be able to store and use it later.
All examples I found on the Internet were pretty advanced, and I suppose they weren't as simple as I want it to be - I just need something similar to Java's :

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
```

Holding the input for later calculations is also important for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following code snippet. `Main.this` is the Activity reference.

```
// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(Main.this);

new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
    .setTitle("Update Status")
    .setMessage(message)
    .setView(input)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             editable = input.getText(); 
             // deal with the editable
         }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             // Do nothing.
         }
    }).show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not understand how I can hold the input; it doesn't let me define a String before it (named name, for example), and then write: name = value.toString().

Comment: The Editable (or, String) has to be defined as a global variable of this Activity, if you need this Editable object to do something later.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother again.
It seems to me that the application continues to run while it is waiting for input. Is there some way to stop in? I mean, I want the application to proceed only after the input has been taken. For example: I want to get the user's name, and then present to it the message "hello %name".

Comment: Yes, the code proceed just after showing the dialog, and this cannot be stopped. What you can do (maybe) is to make the fields of your Activity blank first. After getting the required information, fill the fields with the information.

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is none similar built in Android. But you can look for third party libraries like the one at http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/dialogs.html#inputdialog

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am not sure how to use those libraries, so I think I will look into a solution within Android's given libraries.